# Solving first-order differential equation by exact method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

this first order differential equation is not exact, as

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\ne\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

$({x}-y^{3}+y^{2}\sin(x))dx=(3{x}y^{2}+2y\cos(x))dy$

However, neither of the two integrating factors give functions of a variable alone. So what is left to do to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please write more on how you identify $M,N$ and compute their partial derivatives. As far as I can see, this equation is exact without modifications.

Comment: Do you mean that $-3y^2+2y\sin x\ne-(3y^2-2y\sin x)$ ?

Comment: pM/y=-3y^2+2ysinx , pN/x=3y^2-2ysinx . There is a minus sign difference

Comment: @PatBol No, I mean that $-3y^2+2ysinx  \ne 3y^2-2ysinx$

Comment: @vqngs Please consult https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Your comments are unreadable as is.

Comment: How are $M$ and $N$ defined ?

Comment: M= x−y^3+y^2sin(x)) , N=(3xy^2+2ycos(x))

Comment: @vqngs No, be careful. Your equation is not in the form $$M(x,y)\mathrm{d}x+N(x,y)\mathrm{d}y=0$$ your equation is in the form $$M(x,y)\mathrm{d}x=-N(x,y)\mathrm{d}y$$ because you wrote $$(x-y^3+y^2\sin(x))\mathrm{d}x=(3xy^2+2y\cos(x))\mathrm{d}y$$ not $$(x-y^3+y^2\sin(x))\mathrm{d}x-(3xy^2+2y\cos(x))\mathrm{d}y=0$$ This is why you are getting confused and struggling with the problem.

Comment: I expected a definition, not the particular values.

Comment: @user990563 Asking what they are in this context is just incoherent, though. There is nothing to define. $M$ and $N$ are merely just symbols that stand in for the values given. They are not "defined" as anything, and I ma not sure why you would assume they are defined as anything. This is an exact differential equation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation

Answer (score 2):

Hint: this is most definitely an exact differential equation. The problem is that you have not written it in the form $M(x,y)\mathrm{d}x+N(x,y)\mathrm{d}y=0$, hence why you are failing to see that.

Comment: Thanks, but I am stuck...

Comment: More precisely, the OP is messing with the signs.

Comment: I thought this would solve it: 

$({x}-y^{3}+y^{2}\sin(x))dx+(-3{x}y^{2}-2y\cos(x))dy=0$
 . But it doesn't. dM/dy is still not eq. dN/dx

Comment: @vqngs : You can easily combine terms now, $x\,dx-d(xy^3)-d(y^2\cos x)=0$, which is directly integrable.

Comment: @LutzLehmann how did you get those terms?

Comment: @vqngs: by checking for the pattern $f'(x)g(y)dx+f(x)g'(y)dy=d(f(x)g(y))$. This mostly works because the example was constructed to be solvable.

Comment: @vqngs $\partial_y{(x-y^3+y^2\sin(x))}=-3y^2+2y\sin(x)$, $\partial_x{(-3xy^2-2y\cos(x))}=-3y^2+2y\sin(x)$. They absolutely are equal. I have no idea where you made your mistake with the algebra, but $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}$ absolutely is true. The equation is exact.